# How can i restrict login to an Azure VM using Active Directory?

Tags: azure

I have created a VM in Azure and set "Login with Azure AD" under the Management Section.

But i can still use rdp to login to the machine with username and password.

How can i restrict that so that a user can only connect if they are and Active Directory user ?

Also users can connect to a service running on the machine via a link

http://<vm_ip>/<port_number>

How can i restrict this to AD users as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i restrict that so that a user can only connect if they are and Active Directory user?

To restrict `RDP` access to an `Azure virtual machine` only to users authenticated with `Azure Active Directory` , you can follow these steps.

1. Login to **Azure VM** with Admin user credentials.
2. Disable the **Network Level Authentication**.

[image]

3. Assign user to  **Remote Desktop Group** and `Administrator`  using below command.

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
net localgroup "Administrator" /add "AzureAD\xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
Ex: user VPN:Theja@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com
Get-LocalGroupMember -Name "Remote Desktop users"
```

3. Assign the **RBAC** role to user for login to `VM` with `Azure AD` credentials.

**Assign any role to users.**

```
Virtual Machine Administrator Login- User assigned to this role,Can log in to Azure AD Admin privileges.
Virtual Machine User Login -User assigned this role,Can login in to normal user privileges.
```

4. Modify the downloaded **RDP File** with below Values and save the file.

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
username:s:Theja@Testdemo.onmicrosoft.com (Add your username here)
domain:s:AzureAD
```

5. Login to VM with Azure AD Credentials.
6. Disable the Local Administrator by following the steps.

   **Computer Configuration >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Local Policies >> Security Options >> "Accounts: Administrator account status" to "Disabled".**

[image]

7. Disable the `Administrator` user in `Computer Managment`.
   [image]

8.Once the `'Local Admin'` user is disabled, when I try to log in with the same user, I receive the following error.

[image]

> Also users can connect to a service running on the machine via a link

To restrict the `Azure AD` user for the service inside the machine, you can implement restrictions at either the application level or the server level.